# I need your help for this simple statistics problem.

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

I need help for the following problem:

**In a summer reading program for youth, there is a six week period where the seven Harry Potter books are available.**

**(1)If only three books can be read during the program, in how many ways can the books be scheduled for a youth?**

**(2) What is the probability that book 1, Harry Potter and Sorcerer's Stone, is the first of the three selected books.**

I need your help to understand this statistics problem. Here I did not understand the six week period meaning to use the combination formula.

Please help me thanks.

Comment: Does reading in which week matter here? In other words, if I read the same 3 books in the same order but read them in different weeks, does that count a different way of scheduling?

Comment: I am also confused about it.

Comment: I assume it does count as a different way. Otherwise the questions would be uninteresting.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the 6 week period is just an extraneous piece of information.  The important points are that there are 7 books and a youth can read 3 of them.

In this case, the order in which the books are read is important.  So, reading books 1, 2, and 3 in that order would be a sequence distinct from reading books 3, 2, and 1 in that order.

There are (7 choose 3) ways to select 3 books from 7 and 3! ways to order 3 books, so there are (7! / (3!4!)) * 3! or 7! / 4! ways to schedule 3 books out of 7 or, in other words, 7 * 6 * 5 ways.

The probability that book 1 is the first scheduled book is just the probability of choosing book 1 at random from among the 7 books or 1/7th.

Answer (score 0):

**(1)**

The numbers of combinations (ordered) of books you can choose is $A_7^3$;

The numbers of choices of weeks you can read them in is $C_6^3$;

So there are $A_{7}^{3}\times C_6^3=7\times6\times5\times\frac{6\times5\times4}{3\times2\times1}=4200$ schedules.

**(2)**

Now combination of books are only $6\times5=30$, while choices of week remains the same. So you have $30\times\frac{6\times5\times4}{3\times2\times1}=600$ schedules.